# Scrapy cant get text value even that text appears in response

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to get the promotional price for this item (2x and 3000) https://nuevo.jumbo.cl/mantequilla-con-sal-soprole-250-g/p and I cant reach the text value of that.
Even if I call all the divs in that section i get no result for the div containing that info.
The xpath I was trying to use was:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="info-wrapper"]//div[contains(@class,"prices__wrapper")]/div')
```

what could be the problem in my xpath?

Comment: works on my end: http://ix.io/1qgd . Could you post whole scrapy shell output?

Comment: Same as you, the problem is that I want to catch the "2x" and "3000" or the "6000 x Kg"

Comment: Look at the source code, not the inspector. You'll find that the section 'Todo medio del page' with the discount price is rendered with a `handlebars.js` script and therefore cannot be scraped without Splash of some other extension.

Comment: I was thinking that could be something like that. Any small tutorial for splash? Or any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [3]: response.css('.skuBestPrice::text').extract_first()
Out[3]: '$ 1.949,00'
```

Comment: Im able to grab that value with an extra path in the expression I wrote before, the second price is the one that I need to get and still can't